# Redirecting with sub-domain

Tags: subdomain, web-hosting, document-root

I have about 5 apps I want to host on a server. The main entry server will sit on the main domain while others will be sub.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mainapp
```

I pointed the document root to the mainapp so that when the domain - `(hhtp://example.com)` is called it'll be the app that'll appear.
Other apps are in the same document root

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subapp1
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subapp2
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subapp3
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subapp4
```

The other apps should be called from the browser as this:

```
subapp1.example.com
subapp2.example.com
subapp3.example.com
subapp4.example.com
```

The challenge now is that once I point the document root to an app. I'm unable to access other apps from the browser. How do I make them accessible?

Comment: You need both <VirtualHost> entries for each subdomain and DNS entries. Have you done that? Because you don't mention it.

Comment: Thanks only did it for the main domain. Thanks, I'll revert. after trying it out.